# How to correctly project a tif image using matplotlib-basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal, matplotlib-basemap

I try to display a raster image using gdal and matplotlib-basemap.

I explain here my try using basemap.interp function, for a total structured overview of my process, please look to my [IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/mattijn/pynotebook/1dddcbcba3048aeeccee2092067c08746d445842/ipynotebooks/MapProjectionIssues.ipynb).
First my code to load and project the raster.

```
# Load Raster
pathToRaster = r'I:\Data\anomaly//ano_DOY2002170.tif'
raster = gdal.Open(pathToRaster, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
array = raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
msk_array = np.ma.masked_equal(array, value = 65535)
print 'Raster Projection:\n', raster.GetProjection()
print 'Raster GeoTransform:\n', raster.GetGeoTransform()

# Project raster image using Basemap and the basemap.interp function
map = Basemap(projection='robin',resolution='c',lat_0=0,lon_0=0)

datain = np.flipud( msk_array )

nx = raster.RasterXSize
ny = raster.RasterYSize

xin = np.linspace(map.xmin,map.xmax,nx) # nx is the number of x points on the grid
yin = np.linspace(map.ymin,map.ymax,ny) # ny in the number of y points on the grid

lons = np.arange(-180,180,0.25) #from raster.GetGeoTransform()
lats  = np.arange(-90,90,0.25) 

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats) 
xout,yout = map(lons, lats)
dataout = mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp(datain, xin, yin, xout, yout, order=1)

levels = [-1000,-800,-600,-400,-200,0,200,400,600,800,1000]
cntr = map.contourf(xout,yout,dataout, levels,cmap=cm.RdBu)
cbar = map.colorbar(cntr,location='bottom',pad='15%')

# Add some more info to the map
cstl = map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.5)
meri = map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,60), linewidth=.2, labels=[1,0,0,1], labelstyle='+/-', color='grey' ) 
para = map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30), linewidth=.2, labels=[1,0,0,1], labelstyle='+/-', color='grey')
boun = map.drawmapboundary(linewidth=0.5, color='grey')
```

This will plot the following:

[image: data is offset compare to coastlines]

It's especially clear to see that on the east coast of North and South America there is a offset of the raster data and the coastlines.

I'm clueless how to adapt my code so my data will be transformed in the right projection.

For what it's worth: [My used raster tif file](https://github.com/mattijn/pynotebook/raw/2300c30cc8e9bbcbe959995ce199ec9d8796257a/idata/ano_DOY2002170.tif) (if you download it puts an '-' between 'a' and 'no', before 'ano_DOY..' after 'a-no_DOY..')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong with your own interpolation/reprojecting, but it can be done even simpler.

The `contourf` accepts a `latlon` keyword which, when true, accepts lat/lon inputs and converts it to the map projection automatically. So:

```
datain = msk_array

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
map = Basemap(projection='robin',resolution='c',lat_0=0,lon_0=0)

ny, nx = datain.shape

xin = np.linspace(map.xmin,map.xmax,nx) # nx is the number of x points on the grid
yin = np.linspace(map.ymin,map.ymax,ny) # ny in the number of y points on the grid

lons = np.arange(-180,180,0.25) #from raster.GetGeoTransform()
lats  = np.arange(90,-90,-0.25) 

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

xx, yy = m(lons,lats)

levels = [-1000,-800,-600,-400,-200,0,200,400,600,800,1000]
cntr = map.contourf(xx, yy,datain, levels,cmap=cm.RdBu)

cbar = map.colorbar(cntr,location='bottom',pad='15%')

# Add some more info to the map
cstl = map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.5)
meri = map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,60), linewidth=.2, labels=[1,0,0,1], labelstyle='+/-', color='grey' ) 
para = map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30), linewidth=.2, labels=[1,0,0,1], labelstyle='+/-', color='grey')
boun = map.drawmapboundary(linewidth=0.5, color='grey')
```

[image]

Note that i changed the `lats` definition in order to remove the flipping of your input raster, just a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks great! But.. I can't reproduce your results.. My map stays white, except the 'add some more info' part. Which version of Basemap do you use? I've installed version 1.02 from the additional plugins from pythonxy website.

Comment: The `latlon` keyword is introduced in version 1.05 (im using 1.06). I have updated my answer to do 'manual' coordinate conversion: `xx, yy = m(lons,lats)`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes! That's working perfect. For the time being will use this, and will update to a newer version soon, since 1.02 is quite outdated I see